# Yii2 - AJAX validation without $form->field()

Tags: validation, yii

I have a form, but the input fields are not bound to it, so instead of `$form->field()` I have to use `Html::textInput('ALG['.$x++.'][pcs]', $models->pcs)` because it's like multiple models of the same kind in a single form, but the input fields are in a gridview for a better overview, instead of the Yii way: [collecting tabular input](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-tabular-input) (when you have a few hundred models, it's going to be confusing). Is it possible to use AJAX validation for these *non-form* `Html::textInput()` inputs?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `$form->field()`? If because the complex input name, you can override the default and set yours by passing the name option to the input the same way you assign a class to it.

**Note:** This applies only if you are working with a ActiveRecord.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I have updated the question for better understanding.

Comment: If you organize it properly, yes you can and without leaving the models behavior. You can work with Active Record and  rules. Check the tabular input and you will find the way. If not, you need to create the validation by yourself because ActiveForm the one that manages you forms in client, as far as I know, assumes a model on server side.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<?= Html::activeLabel($model, '['.$x++.'][pcs]'); ?>

<?= Html::activeTextInput($model, '['.$x++.'][pcs]'); ?>

<?= Html::error($model, '['.$x++.'][pcs]'); ?>
```

Where `$model` is an object of ALG model.